# CSV to CSV comparison in R

Tags: r

I need to compare two csv files in R and write the records that is not matching in both the files. I was able to do above task with the below code,

```
 library(dplyr)
a <- c("ads", "ads", "abc")
b <- c(121, 345, 23.300)
c <- c(21,22,23)
srce <- cbind.data.frame(a,b,c)
d <- c("ads", "ds", "abc")
e <- c(121, 345, 23)
f <- c(21,22,23)
trgt <- cbind.data.frame(d, e, f)
colnames(trgt) <- colnames(srce)

#Compare csv files
nn <- anti_join(srce, trgt)
```

The final output gives me rows with mismatch,

[image: Output]

But i need to find out the cells which are mismatch in two files,

[image: Desired Output]

Is there a way to identify the cells which are mismatch rather than the entire records?

Thanks
Balaji.SJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument with `cbind.data.frame`, a simple logical comparison will do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c("ads", "ads", "abc")
b <- c(121, 345, 23.300)
c <- c(21,22,23)
srce <- cbind.data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d <- c("ads", "ds", "abc")
e <- c(121, 345, 23)
f <- c(21,22,23)
trgt <- cbind.data.frame(d, e, f, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(trgt) <- colnames(srce)


# logical comparison:
srce == trgt

         a     b    c
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

---

To compare two dataframes and extract the column names of columns with nonmatches, calculate the `colSums` of the matrix `srce != trgt` and display the names of all columns with `colSums > 0`:

```
names(which(colSums(srce != trgt, na.rm = TRUE) > 0))

[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: Hi @LAP sorry for the late reply. I have large tables with columns more than 300 and rows in millions, so your solution is difficult to check in case of large tables. Please provide any other solution for checking large tables.

Comment: Hi @SJB, which object class are your tables? Matrices?

Comment: Class of the table is DataFrame.

Comment: You could wrap a `which()` around the logical comparison, e.g. `which(srce != trgt)` to get the cell positions of non-matches in the logical result matrix.

Comment: which(srce == trgt) gives me positions of cells which matched...It will be difficult to check for large datasets. Is it possible to get only names of the columns which have unmatched cells.